# Background image size within an iframe is stretched

Tags: css, iframe, background-image, background-size

I'm having a weird issue where background images within an iframe are being stretched to the height of the iframe rather than the size of the div that they're attached to.

Basically, I have a page made by a different agency that  that will live within an iframe on the client's main site. This page has 4 or 5 sections with background images using the following css:

```
background-image: url(../images/bkg1.jpg);
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```

This all works well when we view the document by itself, but when placed within an iframe, the background image size is no longer relative to the div with these styles, it's relative to the entire iframe. We were planning on having the iframe be the height of the document (around 7500px) within it so it looked a little more integrated, but what this does is stretch all of the background images to 7500px. I'm at a loss for why this is happening. Any direction to look in or if anyone has run across this problem before would be a huge help. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I'm having the same exact issue, but it only happens on iPhones.

Comment: Sort of, but not really. We had to do some really hacky stuff to make this work, but we at least figured out why. From what I remember, what is happening is that the background-attachment: fixed value almost acts like a fixed positioned element. It takes the background out of the flow of the page and it's not relative to the window itself. Since it's in an iframe that has a huge height, instead of the window size being the size of your browser window, its calculated as the size of the iframe. So the background-size cover is covering the entire 7500px of the iframe instead of just the window.